# prove without a calculator that if $\tan (p) = 1$ and $\tan(q) = 2$ then

Tags: trigonometry

prove without a calculator that if $\tan (p) = 1$ and $\tan(q) = 2$ then

$${\sin (p+q)\over \cos (p)\cos (q)} = 3$$

My attempt for the numerator:
$\sin (p)\cos (q) + \cos (p)\sin (q)$
After this im stuck

Comment: Is it possible that we actually have $\tan Q=2$?

Comment: @Dr.MV The edits are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin(p+q)}{\cos(p)\cos(q)}=\frac{\sin(p)\cos(q)+\sin(q)\cos(p)}{\cos(p)\cos(q)}=\tan(p)+\tan(q) \tag 1$$

Since $\tan(p)=1$ and $\tan(q)=2$, we find the result in $(1)$ to be $3$, as was to be shown.

Comment: but it is written Q=2

Comment: @kmitov: we know that statement has to be wrong, but until the OP confirms I agree...

Comment: Please explain to me the step (Sin(P)Cos(Q) + Sin (Q)Cos(P))/Cos(P)Cos(Q) ... how is this equal to tan (p) + tan (q)?

Comment: @kmitov The OP confirmed that the edits are correct.  ;-)) - Mark

Comment: @abiessu The OP confirmed that the edits are correct.  ;-)) - Mark

Comment: @myusuf Note that $$\frac{\sin(p)\,cos(q)}{\cos(p)\,\cos(q)}=\frac{\sin(p)}{\cos(p)}\times \frac{\cos(q)}{\cos(q)}=\tan(p)\times 1=\tan(p)$$